# How to slideToggle() on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new with jQuery, and I'm doing fine with basics, but still can't figure out some things with advance use.

This is my example

```js
    jQuery('.hp-single-service a').hover(function() {
      jQuery('.above-content').slideToggle("slow", function() {
        jQuery('.above-content').css({
          "height": "20%",
          "bottom": "0"
        });
        jQuery('.above-content-inner').css("padding-top", "2%");

      });
    });
```

```css
.hp-single-service {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 388px;
  border: 4px solid #f3a12b;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.above-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #73214a;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hp-single-service order-number-1">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="above-content order-number-1">
      <div class="above-content-inner">
        <span class="service-title">Service title</span>
        <span class="service-category">Service category</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img width="954" height="568" src="image-source.jpg" class="attachment-original" alt="Image1">
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create jQuery that will on hover toggle .above-content div to height:20%; bottom:0; and give padding-top:2%; to .above-content-inner div.

For start I'm not sure that slideToggle() is right function for this, so if anyone have better suggestion I'm open for it, just to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even do the same with CSS 3 transitions. Please refer to the following link https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/4kyLgat1/

```
<div class="hp-single-service order-number-1">
<a href="#">
<div class="above-content order-number-1">
  <div class="above-content-inner">
    <span class="service-title">Service title</span>
    <span class="service-category">Service category</span>
  </div>
</div>
<img width="954" height="568" src="image-source.jpg" class="attachment-original" alt="Image1">
</a>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
    .hp-single-service {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 388px;
  border: 4px solid #f3a12b;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.above-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #73214a;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.hp-single-service a:hover .above-content{
  height: 20%;
  bottom: 0%;
}
.hp-single-service a:hover .above-content-inner{
  padding-top: 2%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Oh... I never thought on CSS3, and I should, this is much easier solution, just as I can see I need to play a little with transitions. This your example doesn't work well on my case, I'm not sure why, because your example on jsfiddle works fine. Hover is ok, but when I move mouse no transition, I don't know why. :( Do you have idea how to fix that?

Comment: Can you share your code with me please. It will give me a better understanding of what is wrong

Comment: hi i think the issue is you have added the transition property on hover. Add it to .above-content  class directly. The transition property has to be transition: all 1s ease-out; And inside the ".hp-single-service a:hover .above-content" class you can remove the transition property. This will work correctly.

Comment: I did that, I tried that first, but see now the result. It's not good. :(

Comment: Okey I saw what was happening could you kindly add     bottom: 0%;property to ".above-content" class and remove it from the ".hp-single-service a:hover .above-content" class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84405/discussion-between-snoopy-15-and-shashank-obulampalli).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```js
jQuery('.hp-single-service a').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.above-content').animate({
      "height": "20%",
      "bottom": "0"
    });
    jQuery(this).find('.above-content-inner').css("padding-top", "2%");
  },
  function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.above-content').animate({
      "height": "100%",
      "bottom": "auto"
    });
    jQuery(this).find('.above-content-inner').css("padding-top", "0");
  });
```

```css
.hp-single-service {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 388px;
  border: 4px solid #f3a12b;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.above-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #73214a;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hp-single-service order-number-1">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="above-content order-number-1">
      <div class="above-content-inner">
        <span class="service-title">Service title</span>
        <span class="service-category">Service category</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img width="954" height="568" src="image-source.jpg" class="attachment-original" alt="Image1">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="hp-single-service order-number-1">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="above-content order-number-1">
      <div class="above-content-inner">
        <span class="service-title">Service title</span>
        <span class="service-category">Service category</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img width="954" height="568" src="image-source.jpg" class="attachment-original" alt="Image1">
  </a>
</div>
```

Don't forget that `.hover()` takes two callback functions as parameters - the first one is the `mouseover` and the second one is the `mouseout`.

Comment: Yes, this is right what I need, just I need few fixes. I forgot to write that this .hp-single-service isn't only one on page, I have list of them, so I need hover just for one is hovered. Can you please change that?

Comment: Sure, I used `$(this)` and `.find()` to achieve it.

Comment: This is right what I need! Thank you a lot! You saved my day! :)